# Help with Difficult Integral - $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} f_v (z) = z^{-1} f_{v-1} (z)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, physics, statistical-mechanics

I need a hand with the following integral, I'm not sure how to go about it. I'm trying to verify the following relation, found in Pathria and Beale's Statistical Mechanics, appendix E.

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} f_v (z) = z^{-1}  f_{v-1} (z)$$

Where 
$$ f_v (z) = \dfrac{1}{\Gamma (v)} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{v-1}}{z^{-1}e^x + 1} dx    $$

I get stuck after the $z$-derivative.
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} f_v (z) &= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \dfrac{1}{\Gamma (v)} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{v-1}}{z^{-1}e^x + 1} dx
\\[.5em]
&=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma (v)} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\dfrac{x^{v-1}}{z^{-1}e^x + 1} dx
\\[.5em]
&= \dfrac{1}{\Gamma (v)} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{v-1} z^{-2} e^x}{(z^{-1}e^x + 1)^2} dx
\end{align}

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integration by parts:
$$f'_v(z)=\frac{z^{-1}}{\Gamma(v)}\,\left(-\left.\frac{x^{v-1}}{z^{-1}\,\exp(x)+1}\right|_{x=0}^{x=\infty}+(v-1)\,\int_0^\infty\,\frac{x^{v-2}}{z^{-1}\,\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x\right)\,.$$
Assuming that $\text{Re}(v)>1$, we get
$$f'_v(z)=\frac{z^{-1}\,(v-1)}{\Gamma(v)}\,\int_0^\infty\,\frac{x^{v-2}}{z^{-1}\,\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x=\frac{z^{-1}}{\Gamma(v-1)}\,\int_0^\infty\,\frac{x^{v-2}}{z^{-1}\,\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x\,.$$
Hence, $f'_v(z)=z^{-1}\,f_{v-1}(z)$ for all $v\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\text{Re}(v)>1$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $z\notin\mathbb{R}_{\leq -1}$.  Note that $f_1(z)=\ln(1+z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq -1}$ and
$$f_v(z)=-\text{Li}_v(-z)\text{ for all }v\text{ with }\text{Re}(v)>1\text{ and }z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq -1}\,,$$
where $\text{Li}_v$ is the [polylogarithmic function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) with parameter $v$.

Comment: How did you take the $z$ derivative and turn it into an $x$ derivative?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the integration by parts I was talking about is this:  $$\int\,p\,\text{d}q=pq-\int\,q\,\text{d}p\,,$$ with $p:=-\dfrac{1}{z^{-1}\,\exp(x)+1}$ and $q:=x^{v-1}$.

Comment: And if I may ask another question, it seems like you are saying $dq = (\nu - 1)x^{\nu - 2}$ dx. Shouldn't $dp = \frac{\partial }{\partial z}p dz + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}p dx$? Starting with the integrand in the problem, $$ \int q \frac{\partial }{\partial z}(-p)dx$$ which is where I'm getting confused. I don't know how this is $dp$

Comment: @DWade64  This is an integral with respect to $x$ and $z$ is a constant parameter.  So, $\text{d}p=\left(\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}\right)\,\text{d}x$.